# jQuery toggle more button toggle multiple divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle

I've written jquery for a toggle button...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    /* Needs to be re-written for multiple questions */
    $(".full_question").hide();
    $('.question a').after('<a class="show_full_question" href="#">more</a>');

    $('.show_full_question').click(function() {
    var el = this;
        $(".full_question").toggle(function() {
            $(el).text($(el).text() == 'less' ? 'more' : 'less');
            $(el).toggleClass("hide_full_question");
        });
    });
});
```

it toggles between the full question width and partial width. But when clicked it toggles for all questions on the page. How would I get it toggle only one?

I know it has something to do with $(this) but not sure where it goes... I don't mind changing the html if necessary.

The html is...

```
<h3 class="question">
  <a href="#">What size is the circumference of the earth? I don't really know what it is! Help me! What size is the...
    <span class="full_question"> circumference of the earth? I really don't know!</span>
  </a>
</h3>
```

Comment: Could you also add the html code (or a snippet)

Comment: Yeah post the html for the questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is `$(".full_question").toggle()`, will toggle all elements with the `full_question` class. You need to somehow link the current element being clicked with the proper full_question.

Since you have one `full_question` and one `show_full_question` button under the same parent you can use jQuery to get the parent and find the question to toggle:

```
$(this).parent().find(".full_question").toggle()
```

If you are certain that HTML structure won't change you can also do:

```
$(this.previousSibling.childNodes[1]).toggle()
```

### Here's a [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/Khez/U4Ksp/).